# Ruby - Convert a string concatanated by & into a hash

Tags: ruby, string, hash

I have a string of the form

```
str="a=b&c=d&e=f&...."
```

Question is how do I convert the above str in below form

```
{ "a" => "b" ,  "c" => "d" , "e" => "f" .... }
```

Comment: Is this an HTTP parameter string by chance?

Comment: If you're doing this withing the context of a web framework, there will be a built-in way to handle this.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this method [`URI::decode_www_form`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-decode_www_form).

```
require 'uri'

URI.decode_www_form "a=b&c=d&e=f"
# => [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]
URI.decode_www_form("a=b&c=d&e=f").to_h
# => {"a"=>"b", "c"=>"d", "e"=>"f"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most simple answer is:

```
hash = Rack::Utils.parse_query("a=b&c=d&e=f")

=> {"a"=>"b", "c"=>"d", "e"=>"f"} #output
```

and if you want to revert again then:

```
hash.to_query
```

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity:

```
▶ q = "a=b&c=d&e=f"
▶ require 'json'
#⇒ true
▶ JSON.parse "{\"#{q}\"}".gsub /[=&]/, Hash('=' => '":"', '&' => '","')
#⇒ {
#  "a" => "b",
#  "c" => "d",
#  "e" => "f"
#}
```

The straight way with splits:

```
q.split('&').map { |e| e.split('=') }.to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.split("&").inject({}) do |sum, e| 
  k, v = e.split("=")
  sum.merge(k => v)
end
=> {"a"=>"b", "c"=>"d", "e"=>"f"}
```